# Unparseable date when parsing with AM/PM

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem when parsing a date from a string.

This is my code:

```
String date = "04/01/2016 03:52:33 PM";
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
Date dt = format.parse(date);
```

But it keeps throwing an exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04/01/2016 03:52:33 PM" (at offset 20)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not positive, but it appears it could be an issue with the 'PM' because at spot 20, the 'aa' starts. Perhaps it's case sensitive?

Comment: @Spencer4134 didn't notice that. Tried with "pm" with no luck, same error. Also, I'm getting that string from a database, so changing it wouldn't be the best solution, I think.

Comment: I meant changing 'aa' to 'AA', but that probably won't work unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The am/pm  marker from your default Locale ([Peru - Spanish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4103095/martinc)) probably doesnt match that of the input String

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two aas.

```
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
```

Comment: having an additional `a` won't [cause an exception to be thrown](http://ideone.com/eIWG5T) though...