# Getting UnParsable Date Error for hh:mm a format

Tags: android, datetime, android-6.0-marshmallow, simpledateformat, android-4.4-kitkat

I am passing time as 01:32 PM  for SimpleDateFormat hh:mm a
I am getting error on Marshmallow device Samsung 
But works on Samsung Kitkat Tab Version 
Why is it so ..

Code

```
Date arrStart = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").parse(startTime);
```

Exact Error :

```
Unparseable date: "01:32 PM" (at offset 6)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unparseable date when parsing with AM/PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019559/unparseable-date-when-parsing-with-am-pm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AM/PM** can be seen as an error for the local time.  Try below format:

```
   String s = "01:32 PM";
   Date time = null;
   DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
   System.out.println(time = parseFormat.parse(s));
```

You can also use

```
LocalTime time = null;
DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter 
    = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    time = LocalTime.parse(s, parseFormatter);
} catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
    System.out.println(dtpe.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Worked for me .